# Grant type not supported error in Salesforce

Tags: php, curl, salesforce, salesforce-communities

I am using Sales Force Oauth API. I am using `PHP` and `Curl` for API Integration. When I hit API using Post Method, I am getting this error message `unsupported grant type`.

When I hit the same API using the Postman with the same `headers` and `body`  I'm getting desired response. But getting an error on my webpage. Below is the code. Thanks for the help.

```
<?php 

$url = 'https://mycompanynamegoeshere.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = [
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    'client_id' => 'client id goes here',
    'client_secret' => 'client secret goes here',
];

$data_json = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);

curl_setopt(
    $ch,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json),
        'Cache-Control: no-cache',
        'Connection: keep-alive',
        'Accept: application/json',
    ),
);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;

?>
```

Below is the error message

```
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}1
```

I tried many online solutions. But not getting any output. API works fine in Postman and getting below output:

```
{
    "access_token": "access token comes here",
    "signature": "signature comes here",
    "scope": "scope id comes here",
    "instance_url": "my company salesforce url comes here",
    "id": "my company id",
    "token_type": "token comes here",
    "issued_at": "issue comes here"
}
```

Comment: You _say_ you were sending `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but then you encoded your actual POST data as JSON.

Comment: @CBroe when I hit API using Postman I used the same content type. If its wrong then what should be the correct `Content Type`?

Comment: _"when I hit API using Postman I used the same content type"_ - but then you did not actually encode the data as JSON, I assume?

Comment: What do you get when you use postman's option to generate php code, curl command line  or raw http and try to reuse that?

Comment: post the correct code as answer, i'll happily upvote and you'll get some reputation points :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array(
    $curl,
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://companyname.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=client_id_goes_here&client_secret=client_secret_goes_here',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept: application/json',
            'Cookie: BrowserId=browser_id_goes_here; CookieConsentPolicy=0:1; LSKey-c$CookieConsentPolicy=0:1'
        ),
    )
);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$decoded = json_decode($response, true);
$accessToken = $decoded["access_token"];
curl_close($curl);

?>
```